# Разделение исходящего и входящего трафика на клиенте wireguard

Tags: linux, wireguard

Помогите решить проблемку. Есть сервер VPS. Появилась потребность переправлять через ВПН исходящий трафик. Но по классическому подключению через wg-quick становится недоступным входящие подключения по ssh и на веб-сервер по порту 443. Подскажите пожалуйста, как эти вещи перенастроить.

Конфиг клиента:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <key>
Address = 10.66.66.7/32,fd42:42:42::7/128
DNS = 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

[Peer]
PublicKey = <key>
PresharedKey = <key>
Endpoint = <IP:PORT>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
```